# Isotope with wordpress filtering does not work

Tags: wordpress, jquery-isotope

I check the other posts on this subject but I did not find the answer to my problem.
I follow this tutorial : https://www.aliciaramirez.com/2014/03/integrating-isotope-with-wordpress/

But when I test and click on a filter, nothing happen... I return to the top of my website and that's it. Don't understand why
My js :

```js
jQuery(function ($) {

    var $container = $('#isotope-list'); //The ID for the list with all the blog posts
    $container.isotope({ //Isotope options, 'item' matches the class in the PHP
        itemSelector : '.item',
        layoutMode : 'fitRows'
    });

    //Add the class selected to the item that is clicked, and remove from the others
    var $optionSets = $('#filters'),
        $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

    $optionLinks.click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        // don't proceed if already selected
        if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
            return false;
        }
        var $optionSet = $this.parents('#filters');
        $optionSets.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $this.addClass('selected');

        //When an item is clicked, sort the items.
        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $container.isotope({ filter: selector });

        return false;
    });

});
```

And my php :

```php
<section>

            <ul id="filters">
                <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="selected">Everything</a></li>
                <?php
                    $terms = get_terms("category"); // get all categories, but you can use any taxonomy
                    $count = count($terms); //How many are they?
                    if ( $count > 0 ){  //If there are more than 0 terms
                        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {  //for each term:
                            echo "<li><a href='#' data-filter='.".$term->slug."'>" . $term->name . "</a></li>\n";
                            //create a list item with the current term slug for sorting, and name for label
                        }
                    }
                ?>
            </ul>
        <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=6' ); //Check the WP_Query docs to see how you can limit
            // which posts to display ?>
            <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
                <div id="isotope-list">
                    <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
                        global $post;
                        $termsArray = get_the_terms( $post->ID, "category" );  //Get the terms for this particular item
                        $termsString = ""; //initialize the string that will contain the terms
                        foreach ( $termsArray as $term ) { // for each term
                            $termsString .= $term->slug.' '; //create a string that has all the slugs
                        }
                        ?>
                        <div class="<?php echo $termsString; ?> item"> <?php // 'item' is used as an identifier  ?>
                            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

                        </div> <!-- end item -->
                    <?php endwhile;  ?>
                </div> <!-- end isotope-list -->
            <?php endif; ?>
        </section>
```

thanks a lot for help

Comment: I have tested your code and its working properly. Do you get any errors in your console? Make sure you enqueue isotope script after jquery and your custom js script after. Here an example of enqueue scripts 

function theme_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('isotope','https://unpkg.com/isotope-layout@3/dist/isotope.pkgd.min.js',array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('scripts',get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/scripts.js',array('jquery'));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','theme_enqueue_scripts');

Comment: I have no error in my console. And I have in this order un functions.php : bootstrap and jquery, isotope and my custom js script. When i click on a filter my url is with "#" at the end and he put me at the top of my website

Comment: I think it was a cache problem because it works without changes... Sorry about that. 
The way it works is not quite what I want: I have the last 6 articles when I am on "all". But if I have for example 4 articles of category A and 2 articles of category B, when I click on "category A" I have only the 4 articles. Now I would like to have 6 items in each category. Do you have an idea?

Comment: I dont get the idea of your filter if you gonna show 6 of them again. You can select more than one category for your item. That way they wont hide when you filter.

Comment: Sorry about my comment above. I havent drink my coffee yet. I got your idea and isitope dont have pagination by default. So i have looked in to few examples and you can check this one - https://codepen.io/Igorxp5/pen/ojJLQE .  I will share it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the example i have provided to you - codepen.io/Igorxp5/pen/ojJLQE
This is single term filter so keep that in mind.

For multi term filter you can check this one -https://codepen.io/TimRizzo/details/ervrRq

First prepare your template and query

```
<section>
<ul class="filters">
    <?php 
        $terms = get_terms("category");
        if($terms):
            echo '<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-filter="*">All</a></li>';
            foreach ( $terms as $term ):
                echo '<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-filter="'.$term->slug.'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>';
            endforeach;
        endif;
    ?>
</ul>
<?php 
    $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=-1' ); // We need all posts
        if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
            echo '<div id="container" class="isotope">';
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
                $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(),'category');
                // Filter is working with single term so i am getting first from array or keep posts with single category/tag or w/e.
                echo '<div class="grid-item" data-filter="'.$terms[0]->slug.'">'.get_the_title().'</div>';
            endwhile; 
        endif; 
?>
</section>
```

From there in your js file add the following

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).ready( function() {

        var itemSelector = '.grid-item';  // Item class change if needed
    
        var $container = $('#container').isotope({ // change ID of container if needed
            itemSelector: itemSelector,
            masonry: {
              columnWidth: itemSelector,
              isFitWidth: true
            }
        });
        
        // Responsive pagination
        var responsiveIsotope = [
            [480, 2], // Bellow 480px wide 2 items per page
            [720, 4] //Below 720px wide 4 items per page
        ];
    
        var itemsPerPageDefault = 6; // Items per page unless responsiveIsotope . Over 720px wide 6 items per page
        var itemsPerPage = defineItemsPerPage();
        var currentNumberPages = 1;
        var currentPage = 1;
        var currentFilter = '*';
        var filterAtribute = 'data-filter'; //Used for the filter
        var pageAtribute = 'data-page'; // Used for the pagination
        var pagerClass = 'isotope-pager'; // Class of the pagination container
    
        function changeFilter(selector) {
            $container.isotope({
                filter: selector
            });
        }
    
        function goToPage(n) {
            currentPage = n;
    
            var selector = itemSelector;
                selector += ( currentFilter != '*' ) ? '['+filterAtribute+'="'+currentFilter+'"]' : '';
                selector += '['+pageAtribute+'="'+currentPage+'"]';
    
            changeFilter(selector);
        }
    
        function defineItemsPerPage() {
            var pages = itemsPerPageDefault;
    
            for( var i = 0; i < responsiveIsotope.length; i++ ) {
                if( $(window).width() <= responsiveIsotope[i][0] ) {
                    pages = responsiveIsotope[i][1];
                    break;
                }
            }
    
            return pages;
        }
        
        function setPagination() {
    
            var SettingsPagesOnItems = function(){
    
                var itemsLength = $container.children(itemSelector).length;
                
                var pages = Math.ceil(itemsLength / itemsPerPage);
                var item = 1;
                var page = 1;
                var selector = itemSelector;
                    selector += ( currentFilter != '*' ) ? '['+filterAtribute+'="'+currentFilter+'"]' : '';
                
                $container.children(selector).each(function(){
                    if( item > itemsPerPage ) {
                        page++;
                        item = 1;
                    }
                    $(this).attr(pageAtribute, page);
                    item++;
                });
    
                currentNumberPages = page;
    
            }();
    
            var CreatePagers = function() {
    
                var $isotopePager = ( $('.'+pagerClass).length == 0 ) ? $('<div class="'+pagerClass+'"></div>') : $('.'+pagerClass);
    
                $isotopePager.html('');
                
                for( var i = 0; i < currentNumberPages; i++ ) {
                    var $pager = $('<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="pager" '+pageAtribute+'="'+(i+1)+'"></a>');
                        $pager.html(i+1);
                        
                        $pager.click(function(){
                            var page = $(this).eq(0).attr(pageAtribute);
                            goToPage(page);
                        });
    
                    $pager.appendTo($isotopePager);
                }
    
                $container.after($isotopePager);
    
            }();
    
        }
    
        setPagination();
        goToPage(1);
    
        //When we click a filter grab value ,recalculate pagination, reset pagination
        $('.filters a').click(function(){
            var filter = $(this).attr(filterAtribute);
            currentFilter = filter;
    
            setPagination();
            goToPage(1);
        });
    
        // On resize triger responsive pagination
        $(window).resize(function(){
            itemsPerPage = defineItemsPerPage();
            setPagination();
            goToPage(1);
        });

    });      
});
```

Comment: Thank you! It works almost the way I want it to. In fact, I'd do without the pagination by keeping only the last 6 articles each time.

Comment: And what do I need to change to make it work for posts that are in multiple categories?

Comment: I have tested to with `$termsString = ""; //initialize the string that will contain the terms
                            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                                $termsString .= $term->slug.' '; // create a string that has all the slugs
                            }`and `<div class="grid-item" data-filter="'.$termsString.'">'.get_the_title().' - </div>` But It does not work : I have nothing in all categories :-(

Comment: I retry here and it works : codepen.io/zazzou/pen/wveWZyY but I would like to have just links and no checkboxes for my filter. I tried to replace checked by click on line 28 but it does not work :-(  In fact I would like to do a mix of this codepen and this one :https://codepen.io/zazzou/pen/NWgqVqg